# How do I set maxitemsize in memcached when my init script uses start-stop-daemon

Tags: memcached

I need to temporarily increase the max item size in memcached while I work on a permanent fix for my problem. I found this guide http://www.alphadevx.com/a/387-Changing-the-maximum-item-size-allowed-by-Memcache, unfortunately it tells me to add 
`-I $MAXITEMSIZE` to the line

`daemon --pidfile ${pidfile} memcached -d -p $PORT -u $USER -I $MAXITEMSIZE -m $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN -P ${pidfile} $OPTIONS`

but in my `/etc/init.d/memcached` I've got the line

`start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec "$DAEMONBOOTSTRAP" -- /etc/${NAME}.conf $PIDFILE`

instead. I tried adding the `-I` flag to that line, but I got the error:

`Restarting memcached: start-stop-daemon: invalid IO scheduler policy`

I haven't found any guides that tell me how to do it if my script uses `start-stop-daemon` instead of `deamon`, and I haven't found any documentation about `start-stop-daemon`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, my bad. I had `MAXITEMSIZE=5m` instead of `MAXITEMSIZE=5M`. start-stop-daemon does accept the `-I` flag, you just have to get it right.